# R - extract minimum and maximum values

Tags: r

I have a list something like this:

```
 my_data<- list(c(dummy= 300), structure(123.7, .Names = ""), 
    structure(143, .Names = ""), structure(113.675, .Names = ""), 
    structure(163.75, .Names = ""), structure(656, .Names = ""), 
    structure(5642, .Names = ""), structure(1232, .Names = ""))
```

I want the minimun and maximum values from this list

I have tried using

```
min(my_data) 
max(my_data)
But I get an error: Error in min(weighted_mae) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

typeof(my_data) #[1] "list"
class(my_data) #[1] "list"
```

What is the right way for getting the minimum and maximum from my_data?

Comment: How did you create the `my_data` object? It seems odd to have a list of vectors of length one like that. You can more easily get the range if you unlist the values into a vector: `range(unlist(my_data))`

Comment: `range(my_data)` works fine

Comment: @MrFlick I created my_data from another data without using unlist. May be thats why I have a list of vectors with length one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
my_data |> 
        unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
        range()
```

The following is the same, without piping:

```
range(unlist(my_data, use.names = FALSE))
```

If you want to get minimum and maximum values separately, then you could do:

```
min(unlist(my_data, use.names = FALSE))

max(unlist(my_data, use.names = FALSE))
```